Why is there no Betz type limit for fans?
Betz's law says that only 16/27 of the power in a wind stream can be converted into electrical power by a wind turbine. However, it appears that 100% of the power supplied to a fan motor can be converted into the power in a wind stream. Why is that? Or perhaps I am mistaken?

Interesting. Understanding Fan Efficiency Grades shows fan efficiencies above 90%.
